# Book with a main character who is kidnapped by space pirates and then trained by aliens to become a spy and assassin

Tags: story-identification, books, aliens, space, pirates

The main character starts in a colony ship which is attacked by pirates his family is killed and he is kidnapped and enslaved by the pirates. The pirates get attacked and killed by a winged, alien species.

This species is very traditional and trains him to be a spy and assassin. He is then sent on graduation to a space station to enlist in the human armed forces. He is then trained on a cruiser then graduates and becomes a lieutenant, I think, and then goes and fights pirates on this cruiser. He then finds the same space pirates who attacked his colony ship and ends up finding his younger brother.

Can anyone tell me what this book is called? It's also a little more mature of a book, for it has implied rape.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. In roughly which year did you read this, and when do you think it might've been published? Also, do you recall anything about the cover?

Comment: https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/6766638-empire Maybe?

Comment: Nothing says "mature" like space pirates.

Comment: I read this book 2005-2007 I think. And it has a ship on the cover with the winged aliens to the side. I remember the title was also the name of the ship.